# How perform a t-test on an isobole

Tags: r, t-test

I'm trying to perform a t-test on an isobole, to see if the curvature of the line is significantly different from the additive line.
[Curved Isobole figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlXVy.jpg)

I'm using the isobole function in R to make this figure.
What I am struggling with is most importantly how to perform a t-test on this isobole. If it is necessary, I have also made an isobole made using the method as "CA", if we need to compare two figures.
[Straight isobole](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Miyw.png)

If anybody also knows, I would also like to know how the isobole can show 95% confidence. interval.

In advance, thanks for the help. If any more information is needed, just ask and I will try to provide.

Comment: Please can you clarify what you are trying to do. An isobole is a type of plot. A t-test is a statistical method to determine if there is a significant difference between the means of two groups. You may be able to perform a t test, but you can't perform it on a plot !

Comment: I second @RobertLong's remark, it seems we are missing something from your line of reasoning. You do not need a statistical test to compare areas. If the difference is large, it is large, there is no uncertainty to be estimated. I am failing to see the statistical aspect of the problem.

Comment: Also, it’s unlikely that t-test is the appropriate tool for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.